# exchanging multiple objects between threads and flags in java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am developing an android app in which there are 2 buttons.
These two buttons work on the data returned by a thread
So I am 1)starting a new thread 2)Disabling the buttons 3) Calling the routine
Here is the code for that

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                getPolls();
                answer.setEnabled(false);
                review.setEnabled(false);

            }
        }).start();
```

1.My first question is how can I know that the child thread has completed so that I can re enable the buttons?
2.The method getPolls() called in the thread produces an arrayList. I am returning it via handler as follows

```
//Sending the filled poll questions data to the main thread
        Message qemsg = messageHandler.obtainMessage();

        qemsg.obj=poll;

        messageHandler.sendMessage(qemsg);
```

The message handler code is as follows

```
//Message Handler to get messages from the thread
    private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          polldata=(ArrayList<PollQuestion>) msg.obj;

      }
    };
```

My doubt is how can i send two different objects using message handler?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Message` object has two buildin integer fields `arg1` and `arg2`, and `what` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html). Use them to distinguish messages of different kind in the handler. Example:

```
public static final int TYPE1 = 1;  // use a better name ...
public static final int TYPE2 = 2;
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch(msg.what) {
         case TYPE1: polldata=(ArrayList<PollQuestion>) msg.obj; break;
         case TYPE2: ...
      }
}
```

To communicate that the thread has completed consider using just another message and flag the type (thread completed) using `what`.

Answer (score 2):

I would create [a singleton](http://www.vogella.de/articles/DesignPatternSingleton/article.html), then in your callback set a boolean value to show when it is finished. You can then access this singleton from any part of your code to check to see if it is done. Another way would be a timer. Set up a timer to check to see if it is done and to update your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I would go along with James Holloway's  suggestion of a singleton, that way you have some control over which thread you are talking to.

As for sending different messages they can be identified with the Message.what field

```
qemsg.what = MY_CONST_ID;
```

In the handler you can find the message type you sent and decode it accordingly

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg){
    switch (qmsg.what)
    {

    case MY_CONST_ID:
        //process your message here 
        break;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a static ArrayList that you initialize in getPolls(). In your handleMessage method, set your polldata equal to the static ArrayList. For example, create a class called Constants:

```
public class Constants{
     static ArrayList<PollQuestions> constPolls;
}
```

in getPolls() set Constants.constPolls

```
    Message qemsg = messageHandler.obtainMessage();

    //qemsg.obj=poll;
    // no need to set an object.

    messageHandler.sendMessage(qemsg);
```

Then handle the message:

```
//Message Handler to get messages from the thread
private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      polldata=Constants.constPolls;

  }
};
```

Hope this helps.